# AngularJS service returns data from other service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I want to create AngularJS service to return data from another service.

I tried to use this code:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('angularDjangoRegistrationAuthApp')
  .service('currentUser', function (djangoAuth) {
    var that = this;

    djangoAuth.profile().then(function(data) {
      that.username =  data.username;
    });

    this.getUsername = function() {
      return this.username;
    };
});
```

But when I tried to get username from controller like this:

```
$scope.username = currentUser.getUsername();
```

It was empty.

Comment: Is it possible that `that.username =  data.username;` isn't getting set correctly? Have you put a break point on that line to ensure it's working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

In currentUser service you are setting the username by

```
that.username =  data.username;
```

but in this.getUsername method you are returning it with this.username which is not defined. so try changing it to

```
djangoAuth.profile().then(function(data) {
  this.username =  data.username;
});
```

if djangoAuth service is getting data with profile method correctly then this code should work

OR
you can change following code too:

```
this.getUsername = function() {
  return that.username;
};
```

Comment: That's not an issue, he sets `var that = this;` in the code. Same as running `var bar = {}; var foo = bar; foo.property = 5; bar.property;`